# How to generate random string of specific length in Google Cloud SQL and/or Bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to update a table that has missing data with some unique strings, that I try to generate randomly.

```
SELECT CODE_POINTS_TO_BYTES(
  [CAST(FLOOR(100*RAND()) AS INT64), 
  CAST(FLOOR(100*RAND()) AS INT64), 
  CAST(FLOOR(100*RAND()) AS INT64), 
  CAST(FLOOR(100*RAND()) AS INT64)]) AS bytes;
```

This is what I've tried but I'm getting the following error:

[image]

Comment: use uuids that is unique and has less problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is having problems when adding the fourth parameter.it is able to query up to the 3rd cast.

[image]

and captures the same error when added the 4th parameter.

As @nbk mentioned you can try using [uuid](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/utility-functions#generate_uuid)

> SELECT GENERATE_UUID() AS uuid;

Comment: interesting find, I didn't try with 3. I'd go with generate_uuid and do replacements, seems the way to go.